# Jquery: Hide and show div based on click function of 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a simple task for you Jquery Guru's but I am really battling to do this.

I have two links and I want them to hide and show two forms.

Initially both forms must be hidden, and when you click on button 1 it must show form 1 and when you click the same button again, it must hide form 1. However if Form 1 is shown, and you click on BTN 2 it must hide Form 1 and show Form 2 and similarly if Form 2 is shown, and you click on BTN 2 again it must hide Form 2.

Sort of like Toggling between the two forms but being able to also hide the other form is if it visible.

This is as far as I have gotten. But it is not working like I want, and moreover it seems to be conflicting with the scripts on Bootstrap 4.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#form1").toggle(300);
    $("#form2").hide(300);
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#form2").toggle(300);
    $("#form1").hide(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="btn1">Btn 1</a>
<a href="#" id="btn2">Btn 2</a>

<div id="form1" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <h4>Advanced Search Leather</h4>
  </div>
  <!-- Colours -->
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h4>Form 1</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="form2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <h4>Advanced Search Gumboots</h4>
  </div>
  <!-- Colours -->
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h4>Form 2</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried this. This works by changing between the forms, but if a form is opened, clicking the same button doesnt close (toggle) the form. By the way, this script works in Bootstrap 4.

```js
$("#leather").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#pages div#gumboots").css("display", "none");
  $("#pages div#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
});
$("#gumboots").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#pages div#leather").css("display", "none");
  $("#pages div#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="leather">leather</button>
<button type="button" id="gumboots">gumboots</button>
<div id="pages">
  <div id="leather" class="mydivshow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h4>Advanced Search Leather</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- Colours -->
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4>Colours</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gumboots" class="mydivhide" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h4>Advanced Search Gumboots</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- Colours -->
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4>Colours</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work exactly as you describe

Comment: At least the provided example does work, doesn't it?

Comment: Snippet is working as explained in question.

Comment: Yes it does, but not when placed in my Bootstrap Template

Comment: @RonaldZN add your html so that we can help you

Comment: It would help us immensely if you post said template.

Comment: or create a [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/new#)

Comment: <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script> This is to avoid conflicts with other libraries and your code  behave what it for.

Comment: @RonaldZN is this bootstrap 4?

Comment: Yes it is Bootstrap 4

Comment: Please create your own snippets. The second one is missing the buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function to [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function. [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function will not toggle.

```js
$("#leather").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#pages div#gumboots").css("display", "none");
  $("#pages #" + id + "").toggle();
});
$("#gumboots").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#pages div#leather").css("display", "none");
  $("#pages #" + id + "").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="leather">leather</button>
<button type="button" id="gumboots">gumboots</button>
<div id="pages">
  <div id="leather" class="mydivshow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h4>Advanced Search Leather</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- Colours -->
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4>Colours</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gumboots" class="mydivhide" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h4>Advanced Search Gumboots</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- Colours -->
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4>Colours</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No way dude...I cannot believe it was that simple. You are a lifesaver.

Comment: Yes it is mplungjan, but the first script didnt run in Bootstrap 4. The second script runs in Bootstrap 4.